# Excel Query Access for Environ("USERNAME") Match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to collect data from daily users of and excel workbook.
I have a userform that opens with the workbook but once data is collected I don't need the user to see that user form again.

The form is saving collected data in an access database.  As part of the data sent to the database is the users username grabbed by using Environ("USERNAME")

What I want to do is have excel grab the user name then query the database for a match.
If it's matched skip the form if it doesn't match open the form.

Any help doing this or suggestions as to how the same can be achieved would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Add some VBA and use the function `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` so that it will trigger as the work book opens.

Comment: I'm collecting contact data so the form only contains three text boxes. Payroll Number / Mobile number / Landline number.  The rest of the required data is taken either from the Environ function and an exchange server.  We have some staff with the same name so the Environ("USERNAME") gets me the actual username. All this data is put into a table in an access database I want excel to check the database for a match to the username so that users who have already sent the data don't have to see the form every time they open the workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you did not say where exactly you have a Problem nor post any code I can only hope my answer meets your request...

let's assume you put the username in a string then you could call this:

```
function check_username_already_there(username_str as string) as boolean
   check_username_already_there = false 'set back
  Dim dbe As Object ' As DAO.DBEngine
  Dim db As Object ' As DAO.Database
  Dim dbfile As String
  Dim sSQL As String

    dbfile = "\\yourpath\yourfile.accdb" 'put the full path here
    Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120") ' if Acc2007 or higher
    Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(dbfile)

    sSQL = "SELECT yourtab.Konto From yourtab WHERE (((yourtab.username_in_tab)='" & username_str & "'));"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

       If not rs.EOF Then check_username_already_there = true
    set dbe = nothing
    set db = nothing
    set rs = nothing
 end function
```

if you get back check_username_already_there = true the username already exists and you can skip the form.

I hope this helps,
Max

Comment: Max, Thanks for your answer and please accept my apologies for the lack of code given!  This helps a great deal!